# Calculating the lowest value MOSFET pull-down resistor

Tags: mosfet, low-power, pulldown

I am using the [AO3415](https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3415.pdf) to do high-side switching.

My aim is to reduce power consumption as this low-power device should run for ages on a single battery. System quiescent current is less than 5 μA. (VCC is 5 V)

What is the smallest pull-down resistor value I can use to reduce power consumption but not cause problems?

This P-channel MOSFET is switched a maximum of once every second.

I have checked [How do I calculate the required value for a pull-up resistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23645/how-do-i-calculate-the-required-value-for-a-pull-up-resistor) and [Calculating the pulldown resistance for a given MOSFET's gate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60427/calculating-the-pulldown-resistance-for-a-given-mosfets-gate) among others but am not given a concrete value or formula.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

A 100 kΩ resistor causes 50 μA of loss when the gate is driven high, which is far too much, especially compared to the rest of the system. The gate is high half the time.

How low can I go? 100 kΩ? 470 kΩ? 1 MΩ? 4.7 MΩ? Even lower?

Comment: You say P-channel, but link to an N-channel MOSFET datasheet. Then you say "switching highside" (which *would* use a P-channel device), but show us an N-channel transistor switching on the low side. What's really going on?

Comment: (You use lowest/lower for a desirable resistor value, but that's for *current*. You list values in *increasing* order. (*If* the gate was sure to be driven to either source level or saturation, you don't *need* a pull-to source resistor at all. I'd try 22 M if I found one - you need to keep "the gate-note" clean and dry, anyway.))

Comment: @SimonFitch I've corrected the name now, it's a P-channel MOSFET

Comment: @greybeard the gate isn't driven by push-pull, it's either connected to 5V or left floating, hence the pull-down is needed

Comment: Schematic needed. How fast do you need to switch? How much switching losses are you willing to accept?

Comment: You've removed the image URL from the bottom of the mark-down. If you put it back, please update it to show the intended use of the new P-channel MOSFET, and include both control signal voltages, and the load's supply voltage, because this will be important for high-side switching with PMOS.